# Cordova IOS 8.1.2 File Transfer Plugin Retuns NULL for the $_FILES (php server)

Tags: php, cordova, phonegap-plugins, file-transfer

I am using cordova version 4 and installed cordova plugin camera , file and file-transfer 
My Upload code is

```
  var options = new FileUploadOptions();
  options.fileKey="file"; 
  options.mimeType="image/jpeg";
  var params = {};//new Object();
  params.act   = 'StoreNewReceipt';
  params.FileName=imageURI.substr(imageURI.lastIndexOf('/')+1);    
  options.params = params;
  options.chunkedMode = false;
  options.headers = {
         Connection: "close"
  };  

  var ft = new FileTransfer(); 
  ft.upload(imageURI, url, uploadwin, uploadfail, options,false);
```

In My PHP Code I am getting no values for $_FILES array.

The POST parameters are getting well
The same code worked with IOS 7

I have tried installing the older versions of plugins , Cordova etc. Gone through all suggested posts on internet and when none of them worked i made a post for a solution

Can any one please help me.

Thanks in Advance 
Nijil

Comment: The same code works well for Android